# how to update value in a table from other table

Tags: jdbc, plsql

I need to update value in table with (own value) - (value in other table Like) for an id

I have tried this

```
UPDATE FULLTABLE
            SET FULLTABLE.Balance = FULLTABLE.Balance - AdvBalance.balance
            WHERE FULLTABLE.id= AdvBalance.advid;
```

and this

```
 update fulltable f set f.balance = ( f.balance - 

select a.balance from advbalance a where a.advid=f.advertiserID)
```

first one is throwing error that invalid identifier. second one some other error.

I am using oracle db.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a subselect to get the value from another table:

```
UPDATE FULLTABLE ft
  SET ft.Balance = ft.Balance - (SELECT ab.balance
                                   FROM AdvBalance ab
                                 WHERE ft.id = ab.advid);
```

This will fail if it is possible that the subquery will return more than one row, but if this is the case, then you must decide how to find the right value to be subtracted.